# Database schema of messaging application

Tags: database, database-design, database-connection

In my messaging application, The features I want to provide are:

- Sending a message to multiple people
- Receiving message sent to a user
- Showing message in groups divided by the users, Like in facebook message
- But when a user will send a message to multiple people, It will not be a group message but those messages will go in groups divided by users

My database schema is like this
[image: My database schema]

This schema is able to provide all the functions above but getting the message out from this kind of schema in groups of users is very complex.  Can anyone suggest me some better schema??

The unnamed table is of receivers mapping, forgot to write the name in jpg. :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<del>What is wrong with one table?</del>

message_id 
timestamp 
to 
from 
subject 
body 
attachment_pointer 
origin

...

I'll probably get thrashed for it but...

hmm...good point

```
Messages
message_id
timestamp
subject
body
attachment

MessageReference
mr_id
message_id
to
from
```

edit:  Also found these:

[Messaging system database schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033062/messaging-system-database-schema)

[thread messaging system database schema design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541302/thread-messaging-system-database-schema-design)

[How should I setup my database schema for a messaging system complete with attachments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890481/how-should-i-setup-my-database-schema-for-a-messaging-system-complete-with-attach)

[Database schema for messaging to multiple users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256704/database-schema-for-messaging-to-multiple-users)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use a joining table. This is very simple architecture which lot of giants are using like YouTube, Reddit etc.

[image]

Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/Nt_gWiPMzNM) explaining how only 2 queries will be bringing your app to live.